# Licensing and Obfuscation

Tags: c#, licensing, obfuscation

I have been asked to look into providing a client with a solution for Licensing and code obfuscation. I am no security expert and so I am not even sure exactly what is involved or where to start for providing these features for the client. Any suggestions on reading material or even full solutions would be appreciated (open source over comercial solutions).

Please refer: [CryptoLicensing for .NET](http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm)

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean encryption instead of obfuscation

Comment: @Eric: Why? The question seems to be about obfuscating the code from inspection and provding licensing.

Comment: @larsm because obfuscation is not security.

Comment: @Larsm you are correct. I want to do both

Comment: @Eric: I think that's a matter of opinion. From an organizational point of view, obfuscation is definitly about securing company  propery, the software (Security through obscurity), but not about security of the client.

Comment: @larsm @sreekumar my point is that you need to design your SW to be secure. Security is not paint you can add at the end, like obsfucation.  So it's important to consider obfuscation as false security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the expected amount of users and deployment strategy [SafeNet](http://www.safenet-inc.com) may be an option for you.

At my former company we used the HASP HL product for protection of .NET applications for several years and it works nice and reliable. This is a hardlock based solution, but it is also compatible with Aladdin's software based SRM solution.

The companies portfolio is very flexible, you can deploy the same application software protected, hardware protected, as trial versions, ...

You can create different packages features and/ or protect the application file with an envelope that requires the hardlock (HASP HL) or an windows-like activation (SRM).

Runtimes are available for the most common operating systems.

You can protect .NET or natively complied applications, Java applications, or simply data files and documents.

According to their own information, Aladdin is one of the world's biggest players in software protection. Since they fused with SafeNet two years ago, their portfolio should have grown even to a broader product offering than I am aware of, since I do not use this stuff at my current employer.

As a side note, Aladdin makes sure that the products remain backwards compatible as long as possible. For the mentioned project a t the former employer, we had a more than 6 year old .NET 1.1 legacy application in the field and it still ran with the latest drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but here goes:

Obfuscation is a process to make code hard (for a human) to read ("security through obscurity"). In C# the generated assemblies are typically easy to reverse engineer and obfuscation is therefor heavily used here. There's a number of products that does this. Since you mention CryptoLicensing as your licensing toolkit I'll suggest [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) from the same vendor. I think they are totally separate products so don't expect any advantages over other products with CryptoLicensing. I've used this product and am quite happy.

There's a number of issues to be aware of when doing obfuscation. Code that rely on reflection are prone to problems due to obfuscation (typically refering to a Type by name fails when the class has been renamed to something obscure). Persisentcy is typically prone to such problems. UI is also tricky. Crypto Obfuscator (and other obfuscators) support disabling some obfuscation features to avoid most of these problems. It also supports leaving one or more assemblies out of the obfuscation.

I think it's important that your application is divivded into several sub-libraries/assemblies when doing obfuscation. This enables full obfuscations of parts of your application (e.g. the core), partial obfuscation of other parts (e.g. the UI) and some/none of the rest (e.g. persistent domain objects).

I'm not familiar with Crypto Licensing so I won't cover that part of your question.